# Is Wolfram Alpha giving me a wrong answer?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, mathematica

I have asked for the convergence of the series $\sum (3^n/\sqrt{n})x^{2n+1}$, which has the radius of convergence of $1/\sqrt{3}$ and diverges at $|x|=1/\sqrt{3}$. However, the Wolfram Alpha is apparently giving a wrong answer:

[image]

Is it simply an error, or am I the one who's having the wrong thought?

Comment: Mathematica is wrong. The series doesn't converge at $x= 1/\sqrt 3$ nor at $ x= -1/\sqrt 3,$ which is unsettling. 
I tried plugging in $ (x/\sqrt 3 )^{2n+1}$, and it gave the right answer.$

Comment: It's clearly a bug ! And not a small one ...

Comment: Thank you all for confirmation! I am not getting close to understanding why this error is happening..

Comment: Never trust a software !

Comment: @KurtG. Just hoping that I would be able to cross-check for more complicated computations when using Mathematica, haha.

Comment: Can you post them ?

Comment: @KurtG. I am not doing any computation at the moment. I was mentioning that just thinking about the future, but thanks for your comment.